# Ajax update breaks Primefaces datatable functionality

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

In my application I have a PF layout with a Tree node on west part, and a content part on center where I want to load different pages dynamically with ajax technology.
To get it, this content part contains an `ui:include` tag with `EL` expression. When the user clicks a tree node button, a page is rendered correctly on the center (and that works pretty well!). But some functionality of datatable such as sorting is broken or lost.
Moreover, if a refresh completely the page from the web browser all works OK.

I have simplified my project in order to give you a clean example.
The `index.xhtml`:

```
    <p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" header="Top">
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="100" resizable="true"> 
            <h:form>
            <p:tree id="menuTree" 
                    value="#{menuController.root}"
                    var="node" 
                    selection="#{menuController.selectedNode}"
                    selectionMode="single">  
                <p:ajax event="select" update=":content" listener="#{menuController.setPage(node)}" />
               <p:treeNode>
                   <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
               </p:treeNode>
            </p:tree>
            </h:form>
        </p:layoutUnit>
        <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="50"/>

        <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="60"/>

        <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="centerlayout">   
            <h:panelGroup id="content">
            <c:if test="${not empty menuController.page}">
                <ui:include src="#{menuController.page}.xhtml" />
            </c:if>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</h:body>
```

I would like to remark that I've tried to change the `ui:include` with `EL` and use the conditional render of a container `h:panelGroup` and an static `ui:include`, but the problem persist.

The backing bean of Tree menu:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MenuController implements Serializable {

private TreeNode root;  
private TreeNode selectedNode;
private String pageName;

public MenuController() {  
    root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);  
    TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0", root);  

    TreeNode node00 = new DefaultTreeNode("/list", node0);  
    TreeNode node01 = new DefaultTreeNode("/list2", node0);     
}  

public TreeNode getRoot() {  
    return root;  
} 

public TreeNode getSelectedNode() {
    return selectedNode;  
}  

public void setSelectedNode(TreeNode selectedNode) {  
    this.selectedNode = selectedNode;        
}     

public void setPage(String page){
    this.pageName = page;       
}
public String getPage(){       
    return this.pageName;
}
```

The page that contains data table `list.xhtml` (note that `list2.xhtml` is equal, changing some text to 'watch' the content update):

```
<ui:composition>  

<h:form id="ItemListForm">

    <p:panel header="Title">

        <p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{itemController.items}" var="item"
                     selectionMode="single" selection="#{itemController.selected}"
                     rowKey="#{item.itemid}"
                     paginator="true"
                     rows="10"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30" >

            <p:column sortBy="#{item.itemid}" filterBy="#{item.itemid}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Id"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.itemid}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="#{item.productid}" filterBy="#{item.productid}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="ProductId"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.productid}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="#{item.name}" filterBy="#{item.name}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Name"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="#{item.description}" filterBy="#{item.description}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Description"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.description}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

The `ItemController` bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ItemController implements Serializable {
private Item selected;
private List<Item> items;


public ItemController() {
    this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    this.items.add(new Item("1", "1", "Product 1", "testing sorting"));
    this.items.add(new Item("3", "3", "Product 3", "testing sorting"));
    this.items.add(new Item("2", "2", "Product 2", "testing sorting"));
    this.items.add(new Item("4", "4", "Product 4", "testing sorting"));
    this.items.add(new Item("5", "5", "Product 5", "testing sorting"));
    this.items.add(new Item("6", "6", "Product 6", "testing sorting"));
}

public Item getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(Item selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}    

public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}
```

The class `Item`, very simple:

```
public class Item implements Serializable {

private String itemid;

private String productid;

private String name;

private String description;


public Item() {
}

public Item(String itemid) {
    this.itemid = itemid;
}

public Item(String itemid, String productid, String name, String description) {
    this.itemid = itemid;
    this.productid = productid;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getItemid() {
    return itemid;
}

public void setItemid(String itemid) {
    this.itemid = itemid;
}

public String getProductid() {
    return productid;
}

public void setProductid(String productid) {
    this.productid = productid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

Finally, I'm working with:
Java EE 7
PrimeFaces 3.5 Community
JSF 2.2
Glassfish 4
NetBeans 7.3.1
Safari browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is taht Primefaces 3.5 doesnt go well with glassfish 4 switch to primefaces 4.0-SNAPSHOT and I guess it might work

Comment: I have exactly the same stack as you except for netbeans 7.4 beta and i had ajax problems on a p:commandButton fixed it by upgrading to primefaces-4.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Ou yeaahh! it works with primefaces 4.0-SNAPSHOT. Thank you a lot! I was blocked and surely I wouldn't revise these point ever.

Comment: took me 3 business days to figure out :) credits to BalusC he pointed me the right way

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I speak english not well, but this happens because PF include to the page only javascript that needed for succesfully rendering of  components that are present on the page. If you include component  to the page dinamically by using for example ui:include, page will not contain js for  rendering of this component

Comment: Suppose this is the problem: what then is the solution?